# How to stop execution while showing alert with Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am showing alert using

```
    import {Alert, NavController} from 'ionic/ionic';
    .............
    var alert = Alert.create({ .....
    .....
    });
    nav.present(alert)
    console.log('fooo'); //This gets executed before 'ok' is clicked or the alert is closed
```

It shows up, but the execution of next lines are not halted as in with generic alert. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you use for alert. But alerts I used leverage promises. I mean when you click on an "ok" button in the alert, the corresponding promise is resolved. So I would say to move the code of next lines into the callback you previously set on the promises.

I would like to be more precise but you only provide one line of code without any other hints ;-)

Hope it helps nevertheless.
Thierry

Comment: I already did this with with something similar - observable. I thought there could be a better way.

Comment: Sure! If you can use observables at this level, go ahead ;-)